# What is the part of speech of this "supreme" after a subtle "as"? Is it a noun or an adjective?

Tags: parts-of-speech

The sentence I came across,

> The Qing regime still saw itself as **supreme** on the planet.

I might regard the word "supreme" as a noun because it follows a preposition word "as". But if it's a noun, I think it should be "a supreme". What's more, I find the word "supreme" is rarely used as a noun nowadays.

Then I pay attention to "as" here. Now I am not sure if it is a preposition.

Help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Qing regime still saw itself as supreme on the planet.

Here the word is being used as an adjective - it is describing the Qing regime.  Or rather, in this case, it is describing the Qing regime's own perception of the status of the Qing regime.

> I see myself as *a* human being.

Here there is an indefinite article, followed by an adjective/noun pair.   I am a being.  What kind of being?  a human being.

> I see myself as *the* best dancer in the room.

Here there is a definite article, followed by a superlative phrase.

> I see myself as fat.

No article, and an adjective.

In all cases, *as* is being used as a *preposition*.

Comment: "as" can be used as an adverb.

Comment: The preposition "as" is unusual.  Most prepositions take objects.  "As" takes a complement.  It's this unusual behavior that leads dictionaries to label it an adverb.

Answer (score 0):

*a supreme?* No!

The word *supreme* is **not** a noun. It's an adjective word there. Refer any dictionary. Being an adjective, it *won't take* any article.

Now, the *placement*.

> A red apple *(adjective 'red' followed by a noun 'apple')*

Now, adjective *can* go without being followed by a noun!

> An apple is *red*

Look at this example from [Oxfordictionaries (#1.1)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supreme):

> *'on the race track he reigned **supreme.'***

And from [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/REIGN)

> *"Money reigns supreme here"*

Now, following 'as'.

[Adjectives may also follow **the word they modify**.](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/adjAdv.asp)

> *The technology is **state-of-the-art***.